# How to define a function that checks each column of 'object' dtype and gets those columns which can be converted to datetime format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, type-conversion

The below is what I tried but didn't work quite well.

```
def print_dtcols(DF):
  colms = DF.columns.values[DF.dtypes.values == 'object']
  names = []
  for colm in colms:
    try:
      DF[colm] = pd.to_datetime(DF[colm], infer_datetime_format=True, errors = 'raise')
      names.append(colm)
    except ValueError:
      pass
  return names
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': ['a', 'b', 'c','d','e'],
                   '1': ['2015-12-27','2015-12-28', '2015-12-29','2015 12-31 10:00','2016/01/01 15:00'],
                   '2': [11,12,13,14,15],
                   '3': ['2015-12-31','2015-12-29', '2015-12-30','2016-01 11 23:59','2016/02/01 22:00'],
                   '4': ['2015-02-31','2015-02-29', '2015-02-30','2016-03 11 23:59','2016/04/01 22:00'],
                   '5': ['2015-04-31','2015-04-29', '2015-04-30','2016-05 11 23:59','2016/06/01 22:00'],
                   '6': ['2015-04-31','2015-04-29', '2015-04-30','2016-05 11 23:59','2016/06/01 22:00']})

print_dtcols(df)
```

the output was ['1','3'] and I was expecting that to be ['1','3','4','5','6']

Comment: please correct the indentation of you code and consider adding tags 'python' and 'pandas' so that the question is easier to find. Welcome to SO ;-)

Comment: apologies for my bad :) just being new around here.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong dates noticed due to which the define function did not work. There is no 31st day in April and hence the code dint work. Corrected the dates and now it is working.